# Postgres add parameter to interval statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-function

I am trying to add a parameter inside a postgres function interval statement.  Not sure how to add it...

Like follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_date(number integer)
RETURNS table (date_value date)
AS
$body$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY (select (now() + interval '$1 days') ::date as column_value);
END;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
RETURN QUERY select (now() + number * interval '1 day') ::date as column_value;
```

Expression `number * interval '1 day')` gives you an interval of `number` days.

You could also use `make_interval()`:

```
RETURN QUERY select (now() + make_interval(days := number))::date as column_value;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eeff539479ca46182ec12154e3207870)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add an integer to a `date` value directly, which adds the number of days. So if you use `current_date` no casting is needed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_date(number integer)
  RETURNS table (date_value date)
AS
$body$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY select current_date + number;
END;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

But I don't understand why you use a set-returning function for a single value. A scalar SQL function would be better in this case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_date(number integer)
  RETURNS date
AS
$body$
  select current_date + number;
$body$
language sql
stable;
```